# Text over skewed div with background image

Tags: html, css

Is there a way a to put text over a div which has been skewed with a background image on it? Heres an example of what I'm trying to achieve but because I'm using the ::before pseudo element the text appears behind the image.

**Html**

```
<div class="diag-right">Text Here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.diag-right {
    height:220px;
    float:right;
    width:260px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    left: -120px;
    transform: skew(-20deg); 
    -o-transform: skew(-20deg); 
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg); 
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg); 
    -sand-transform: skew(-20deg);
}

.diag-right::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 370px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: -40px;
    background: url("http://imgur.com/T25mFEV.jpg") 0 0 repeat;
    transform: skew(20deg); 
    -o-transform: skew(20deg); 
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg); 
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(20deg); 
    -sand-transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

**Live Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/jGJe3/

Is there a way to do this or a suitable work around?

Comment: I didn't understand why do you need the :before element for? Why not just applying the background-image to the Div itself? This way you'll have the text shown over the background-image

Comment: i need to unskew the background image. Thats why the :before is used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
.diag-right::before {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

to place `::before` behind the `.diag-right` element. Just note, that this solution is not usable, when `.diag-right` has a background of its own, because then that will lay above the `::before`.

Comment: This works but i still need to unskew the text as the text is slanted any ideas?

Comment: Just slant the `::before`, remove the `skew` from `.diag-right`. Would that work for you?

Comment: Never mind i got it. I can add a class around the text and unskew it that way. Thanks for the answer much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the `::before` element there.

Check this <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/jGJe3/3/)</kbd>

**CSS**

```
.diag-right {
        color:white;
        height:220px;
        float:right;
        width:260px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        outline: 1px solid transparent;
        left: -120px;
        transform: skew(-20deg); 
        -o-transform: skew(-20deg); 
        -moz-transform: skew(-20deg); 
        -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(-20deg); 
        -sand-transform: skew(-20deg);
        background: url("http://imgur.com/T25mFEV.jpg") 0 0 repeat;
    }
```

Comment: That skews the text, too, unlike OP's original version.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<div class="diag-right">Text Here
    <div class="content">
        I think this will help u .
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.diag-right {
        height:220px;
    float:right;
    width:260px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    left: -120px;
        transform: skew(-20deg); 
        -o-transform: skew(-20deg); 
        -moz-transform: skew(-20deg); 
        -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(-20deg); 
        -sand-transform: skew(-20deg);
    }

    .diag-right::before {
        position: absolute;
        width: 370px;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: -40px;
        background: url("http://imgur.com/T25mFEV.jpg") 0 0 repeat;
        transform: skew(20deg); 
        -o-transform: skew(20deg); 
        -moz-transform: skew(20deg); 
        -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(20deg); 
        -sand-transform: skew(20deg);
    }
.content {
    opacity: 0.6;
    height : 100px;
    width: 150px;
    color: #fff;
}
```